# MySQL Queries: find any record with a PENDING status and find any records with a FAILED status

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three columns with three values that can be set for each column

```
Column_1 | column_2 | column_3
________ | ________ | ________
COMPLETED| FAILED   | PENDING
COMPLETED| COMPLETED| COMPLETED
FAILED   | COMPLETED| COMPLETED
COMPLETED| PENDING  | COMPLETED
COMPLETED| COMPLETED| PENDING
COMPLETED| COMPLETED| COMPLETED
COMPLETED| COMPLETED| COMPLETED
PENDING  | COMPLETED| COMPLETED
```

Looking for two queries, One to find any record with a PENDING status and the other to find any records with a FAILED status

NOTE: PENDING and FAILED should have the same logic

```
Query: PENDING
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE Column_1 = 'PENDING' OR Column_2 = 'PENDING' OR Column_3 = 'PENDING'

Query: FAILED
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE Column_1 = 'FAILED' OR Column_2 = 'FAILED' OR Column_3 = 'FAILED'
```

These queries are not pulling the correct records. I think it's matching the first condition in the WHERE clause and then doing the OR clause as a separate condition. I've tried a couple variations but still no luck.

```
Alt Query: 
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE Column_1 OR Column_2 OR Column_3 = 'PENDING'
```

So for the PENDING status, the query should return 4 rows for the data grid above
and for the FAILED status, the query should return 2 rows for the data grid above

Comment: Your first set of queries look fine - what's the problem?

Comment: what are you getting? those first 2 queries look fine at first glance to me... never tried that alt query style before... but it looks funny to me :)

Comment: It's forcing the WHERE condition to be a separate constraint so the OR conditions are considered as a separate constraint. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping parenthesis around each condition to see if that works:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE (Column_1 = 'PENDING') OR (Column_2 = 'PENDING') OR (Column_3 = 'PENDING')
```

I am actually not familiar with mysql, but this might be a better way, anyone can correct me if I am wrong:

SELECT * FROM tbl
   WHERE 'PENDING' IN(Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4)

Again, if the above is incorrect, I apologize.

Comment: I like the update as well, looks cleaner than having all the OR conditions. Thanks again

Comment: Great. Nice to hear it is working.  This is my first accepted answer, lol, so it is an historic day :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first query looks correct. It is possible that you are using `char` datatype and this is confusing things, i.e., you may need to add trailing spaces. Can you post your schema?

Comment: A quick way to check this would be to change the queries to use LIKE; i.e. "WHERE column_1 LIKE "PENDING%" OR column_2 = "PENDING%" ...". If that works, it's clear that you've got space issues.

Comment: No space issues as the data is entered by script and is trimmed before insertion

Answer (score 0):

If the behaviour is weird, I'd try parenthesis.

```
Query: PENDING
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE ((Column_1 = 'PENDING') OR (Column_2 = 'PENDING') OR (Column_3 = 'PENDING'))

Query: FAILED
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE ((Column_1 = 'FAILED') OR (Column_2 = 'FAILED') OR (Column_3 = 'FAILED'))
```

Though, I'll be honest, I don't know why that would work better/worse: since all you're using is "OR" it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE Column_1 OR Column_2 OR Column_3 = 'PENDING'
```

This is definitely *not* going to return what you think.  Here's how it's evaluated:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE (Column_1) OR (Column_2) OR (Column_3 = 'PENDING')
```

Using a string column as a truth term evaluates the string as an integer, which in these examples is 0, interpreted as `false`. So this is like:

```
WHERE (false) OR (false) OR (Column_3 = 'PENDING')
```

The effect is that it ignores the first two columns and returns rows only where the third column matches `'PENDING'`.

In other words, you gave a query that is syntactically valid but doesn't have the result you intend.

The first two queries you gave do return 4 rows where any column is `'PENDING'` and two rows where any column is `'FAILED'`.  I just tested this and it works.  If it doesn't match your expectations, perhaps you can clarify:

- What query did you try?
- What was returned?
- What result were you expecting instead?

Comment: Bill, Curious, does t-sql or pl-sql do the same thing?

Comment: Why, also in this case are the strings turned into 0 and not 1.

Comment: In MySQL, casting a string to an integer uses any leading numeric digits in the string, defaulting to 0 if there are none.  So `'123abc'` casts to the integer 123, but `'abc123'` casts to the integer 0.

Comment: In Microsoft or Oracle (or standard SQL), you can't treat an integer as a boolean implicitly as you can in MySQL, so I don't think your query would have valid semantics at all.  In other words, "`WHERE 1`" is valid only in MySQL.  In other brands, you'd have to use either "`WHERE true`" or "`WHERE 1 = 1`" or something.